# Homework Help - Checking data on Form button

Tags: c++, forms

I'm really not used to creating Forms with any programming language and I'm still learning about in. Currently, I have a homework that involves Form in C++.

I would appreciate your help since I'm used to code in win32 rather than Form. I feel like a total stranger even though it's in the same language that I'm currently learning.

Here's the question:
In the button btn_calculate, write the codes that can validate the input sales amount is in correct format (double). If wrong input type is given, show a pop up window with error message “please enter amount in number only”. Calculate the total payment amount by adding 6% of goods and services tax to the entered sales amount. Display the total amount in the label lbl_total with the message given.

The problem:
In the button btn_calculate, write the codes that can validate the input sales amount is in correct format (double).

I'm clueless on how to proceed with this problem but I've already finished up coding the rest of the questions except the first sentence of the problem.

This is the logic that can I came up with but I know it is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtbox_amount->MaxLength; i++)
        {
            if (txtbox_amount[i] == 'A' /*until*/ 'Z' /*capital and lower case character*/)
            {
                //throw 0;
            }
        }
```

This is the my whole logic for the question:

```
private: System::Void btn_calculate_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < txtbox_amount->MaxLength; i++)
        {
            if (txtbox_amount[i] == 'A' /*until*/ 'Z' /*capital and lower case character*/)
            {
                //throw 0;
            }
        }           

        double amount = Convert::ToDouble(txtbox_amount->Text);

        if (amount > 0)
        {
            double total = amount * 1.06;
            lbl_total->Text = "The total payment amount is RM" + total;
        }
        else
        {
            throw 1;
        }
    }
    catch (int errorNum)
    {
        if (errorNum = 0)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Please enter amount in number only", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons::OKCancel,
            MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        }
        else if (errorNum = 1)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Negative input! Try again.", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons::OKCancel,
            MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        }           
    }
}
```

I really would appreciate your help and inputs on how to tackle this problem so that I can improve in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `MaxLength` doc:

> Gets or sets the maximum number of characters that can be manually entered into the text box.

If you want to get the length of your Textbox's content, you have to usethe property `Length` of the `String^` returned from `Textbox::Text`.

Next you have to check if `txtbox_amount->Text[i] >= 'A' && txtbox_amount->Text[i] <= 'Z'` and the same with lowercase characters.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, Would you mind explaining more on the to use the property Length of the String^ returned from Textbox::Text and some pseudocode on it? in win32, I would always use sizeof(array) / sizeoff(array[0]) if an array is involved.

Also, when i try to edit the checking part, the code for the conversion became an error and the Convert is not highlighted into a different colour. Is there a reason behind it?

double amount = Convert::ToDouble(txtbox_amount->Text);

Comment: I can't explain this better than the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx . String is an object ( you don't care about how is implemented, if with an array or not) and you know that this object has the `length` property, you can think of it as the size of your array of chars, but it's more complicated and you definitely need a manual.

Comment: Alright i think i got the idea of the Length property but for now, I'm still stuck on how to write the codes for it as I barely know the majority of C++ syntax.

Do i write it like: if (int i = 0; i < String(txtbox_amount.Length); i++)?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < txtbox_amount->Text->Length; i++)`

Comment: I didn't expect the syntax to be like that. OMG. Thank you so much for this!